# Bug with IndexOf in .NET 7.0 with non-spacing characters?

Tags: c#, .net, contains, indexof, .net-7.0

I'm seeing a weird issue with .NET 7 with the string APIs IndexOf and Contains. I'm using C#. To repro:

`("Foo" + (char)1618).Contains("Foo")` returns true .... yet

`("Foo" + (char)1618).IndexOf("Foo")` returns -1

1618 is a non-spacing Unicode character.

However, when I add a space before the Unicode character like this:

```
("Foo" + " " + (char)1618).IndexOf("Foo")
```

It returns 0 as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Dan

Comment: To be sure, we are talking about the [Unicode Character 'ARABIC SUKUN' (U+0652)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/652/index.htm) character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`string.Contains(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-string)):

> This method performs an ordinal (*case-sensitive* and **culture-insensitive**) comparison. The search begins at the first character position of this string and continues through the last character position.

While [`string.IndexOf(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-string-indexof(system-string)) is using `CurrentCulture`:

> This method performs a word (*case-sensitive* and **culture-sensitive**) search using the current culture. The search begins at the first character position of this instance and continues until the last character position.

Provide `StringComparison` parameter so they are equivalent:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(("Foo" + (char)1618).Contains("Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)); // False
Console.WriteLine(("Foo" + (char)1618).IndexOf("Foo")); // -1
```

Or

```cs
Console.WriteLine(("Foo" + (char)1618).Contains("Foo")); // True
Console.WriteLine(("Foo" + (char)1618).IndexOf("Foo", StringComparison.Ordinal)); // 0
```

But the best option is to always pass the `StringComparison` parameter for consistency.

Also [Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus) article can be useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. Adding the StringComparison.Ordinal parameter fixed the problem. Very much appreciated.